# DataContractSerializer, Ordering inconsistency between .Net and Mono

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

For DataContractSerializer, items in XML must be ordered.

It is by "Order" attribute. Or in alphabetical order for .NET

For a Mono, it is ignored, so order is as data members mentioned in the serializable class. The bug with Mono is described here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10545

Now, the problem is, we have a big project working on Mono. There are tons of config (XML-Config) files. As well as tons of Serializable objects.

In order for this to work in .Net, while still to be compatible with both, Mono and .Net, I have following options:

1. Explicitly add "Order" attribute to each of the serializable objects. So, .Net will repeat the same same numbering
2. Switch to the XmlSerializer. For this one I have to change attributes which are different between both. E.g., XML one includes all attributes unless it is told opposite (ignore attribute)

Both #1 and #2 assume lot of work. Is there a way or Serializer implementation, which will reuse existing Data classes done for DataContractSerializer?

Comment: Can you simply reorder the members so that the .NET order _happens_ to match the declaration order, thus being compatible with Mono? EDIT: nm, I guess that kinda falls under your #1 option anyway.

Comment: Even worse, this way I will need to change (reorder) items in config files as well. Including client's config files

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason to stick with `DataContractSerializer`. I've had good experiences with `XmlSerializer`; at least it also provides a bit more control over how the information is serialized/deserialized (and when you need to turn your control up to 11, you can implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) It _may_ be slightly less brittle to future changes or platform/framework implementations. Your mileage may vary though. Just ensure you have a nice separation of your DTO and business layers.